# PowerShell script to delete lines with timestamp and blank lines

Tags: powershell, null

I'm very new to PowerShell and i'm looking a way to read a file and delete the line if the timestamp is more than 20 days old or blank, and then rewrite it into a new file.

My script is working but if I have a blank line, it fails. Here's the script.

```
$Culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$Format = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$Paths = "D:\xxx\yyyy\log.txt","D:\xxx\zzzz\log.txt"
$Day = "20"

Foreach ($Path in $Paths)
{
  Get-Content $Path | where { [datetime]::ParseExact(([string]$_).Substring(0,19), $format, $culture) -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Day) } | set-content $Path".new"
}
```

I try to check if string is null before the where like this

```
Get-Content $Path | if(!([string]$_)::IsNullOrEmpty) | where { ([datetime]::ParseExact(([string]$_).Substring(0,19), $format, $culture) -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Day)) } | set-content $Path".new"
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if()` can't be piped.

You need to use `Where-Object` similar to the way you already have done:

```
Get-Content $Path |
    Where-Object {$_} |
    Where-Object { ([datetime]::ParseExact(([string]$_).Substring(0,19), $format, $culture) -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Day)) } |
    Set-Content $Path".new"
```

Note that `{$_}` is shorthand for "this has a value"

Comment: Alternatively you can extend your existing `Where-Object` to have `-and` and `-or` clauses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.